# Table column in table of content in ConTeXt

Tags: table-of-contents, context

I've been trying to implement TOC (see screenshot below) in ConTeXt but can't seems to get the additional headers (like table column).

[image]

Advice or guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please be a bit more specific of what you want to achieve, and what you got stuck upon? Also, if you share some minimal code you are working with, it might be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just place the TOC without heading and add it manually. Then change the list title to what you want to see in the TOC.

```
% define new head toc from title
\definehead[toc][title]
\setuphead[toc][
    style={\WORD\bf},       % change style to uppercase and bold
    incrementnumber=list,   % add it to toc
]

\setuphead[title][
    incrementnumber=list,   % add it to toc
]

% setup which elements are part of toc
\setupcombinedlist[content][
    list={title, toc, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection},
    alternative=b,   % style of toc
]

% setup style of toc
% margin is distance from left margin, width is the space between number and title
\setuplist[title][margin=30mm, style={\WORD\bf}, pagestyle={\word}]
\setuplist[toc][margin=30mm, style={\WORD\bf}, pagestyle={\word}]
\setuplist[chapter][margin=10mm, width=20mm, style={\WORD\bf}, pagestyle={\word}]
\setuplist[section][width=10mm, margin=30mm]
\setuplist[subsection][width=10mm, margin=40mm]
\setuplist[subsubsection][width=10mm, margin=50mm]

% pages before toc get roman numerals
\definestructureconversionset[frontpart:pagenumber][][romannumerals]
\definestructureconversionset[bodypart:pagenumber][][numbers]

\starttext
    \startfrontmatter
        \title{Abstract}

        \starttoc[
            title={Chapter\hfill Title\hfill Page},
            list={Table of Contents},
            bookmark={Table of Contents},
            marking={Table of Contents},
        ]
            \placecontent 
        \stoptoc
    \startfrontmatter

    \startbodymatter
        \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \section{First section}
        \subsection{First subsection}
        \subsubsection{First subsubsection}
        \subsubsubsection{First subsubsubsection}
        \section{Second section}
        \subsection{Second subsection}
        \chapter{Chapter 2}
        \section{Third section}
        \subsection{Third subsection}
    \stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

Most of the code you find in the [wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table_of_Contents)[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your example help me to understand the concept further. And you're right, I didn't read the page properly.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, for other types of lists, for example, list of figures. I'm using [\startcolumns](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startcolumns) to achieve similar result.

```
\title{List of Figures}
\startcolumns[n=3]
    \bf{FIGURE NO.}
    \column \bf{TITLE}
    \column \hfill \bf{PAGE}
\stopcolumns
\blank[0.5em]
\setuplist[figure][margin=0mm, width=25mm]
\placelist[figure,widetable]
```

[image]